# User keyboard input to end while loop

Tags: shell, keyboard-events

I'm trying to write a script that will log command history into a temporary PID.cmd file. I'm getting stuck on how to end the script when a combination of keys are hit on the keyboard.

```
until [ <CTRL+C> ]
do
    read -p "$PWD\$" cmd;
    echo "$cmd" >> $$.cmd
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -p "$PWD\$" cmd; do
    echo "$cmd" >> $$.cmd
    ...
done
```

The loop will terminate when the input stream ends.  If stdin is from a tty, that happens when the user types ctrl-D.  `SIGINT` should also terminate the loop, as read will then fail.  (`SIGINT` is sent in response to ctrl-C.)